# Customize Default WiX Bootstrap GUI

Tags: html, wix, wix3.9

I want to create an additional button in default GUI of Bootstrapper set-up project. This button should be added when the set-up complete GUI is presented. I want to start an application when this button is clicked.  Please see the attached screenshot as the current implementation, I want to modify it like, Lauch My app button should shown in testbootstrap completed UI, Is it possible?, if possible, please guide me for solving this soultion. [image],

Please help.

Comment: Could you add  what you have already tried. So we can help fix your mistake instead of someone doing the work for you.

Comment: I tried a custom UI shown after the installation completed in the .msi installer. The same I want to do  after bootstrapper installation. means that I want to edit default burn ui shown by bootstrapper project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added the following item in **bundle.wxs**

```
 <Variable Name="LaunchTarget" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]\test.exe "/>
```

Then changed the string  ***SuccessLaunchButton*** in *.wxl* file to the Launch my App.

Thank you,

George